# angular 2 4 5 - Cannot read property 'name' of undefined angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

sorry, English a little

**I want : Show in view after back-end server communication. 
         or another solution**

> view.html

```
<label> userId : {{ element.userId }} 
<label> brandName : {{ elemnet.brand.name }} ==> ERROR

Cause of error : I think Object initialization issues on the component.ts
```

> component.ts

```
element: { [k: string]: any } = {}; ==>  Not defined element.brand{}

ngOnint(){
this.getElement()
}

getElement(): void{
this.http.get(getUrl)
     .map(res => {
          this.element = res;

         **element** ==> { 
                      userId : 1,
                      brand {
                             name: 'brandName',
                             id : 1
                            }
                     }
     })
     .catch()
}
```

> Temporary resolution
>
> view.html

```
<label> userId : {{ element.userId }} 
<label> brandName : {{ elemnet.brand?.name }} ==> Resolve
```

I want to solve this problem.

Thank you.

have a good day.

Comment: your response have only one element? or array of objects?

Answer (score 2):

Your temporary solution isn't temporary but correct.

```
Temporary resolution

view.html

<label> userId : {{ element.userId }} 
<label> brandName : {{ elemnet.brand?.name }} ==> Resolve =>> Keep this solution
```

Comment: Thank you.

i want Object initialization in typescript. ( Like a interface or Class)

example) 
element : {
  userId: string,
  brand : { 
                id: number,
                name: string
              }
}

I tried, but I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this solution

```
<label> userId : {{ element?.userId }} 
<label> brandName : {{ elemnet?.brand?.name }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`<label *ngIf="element"> userId : {{ element.userId }} </label>`

`<label *ngIf="element"> brandName : {{ element.brand.name }} </label>`

In component.ts file don't initialize element. Leave it like this

`public element;`